# Django forms not producing output

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.6

So I tried to create a form in my views.py file, which when rendered in the template did not show. I tried to do this in the manage.py shell like this:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class Test(forms.Form):
...     about = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
...     animal = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
...     email = forms.EmailField()
... 
>>> form = Test()
>>> form.as_p
<bound method Test.as_p of <Test object at 0xa9e446c>>
>>>
```

As far as I'm aware, the `form.as_p` should give me the form, but instead it returns the output above. I assume what's happening in the shell is what's happening in my view and template. Forms do not render with bound data either.

Any idea what is causing this behavior? I believe I've followed the [Django docs on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) closely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`as_p` is a method, so if you want to use it in the interpreter, you should use `as_p()`. The method lookup and call are done automagically by the template renderer, so that's why you don't need the brackets in a template.

Comment: When I do `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template, it doesn't render. I'm passing `form` via `return render(request, 'new_profile.html', {form: form,})`

Comment: you have to use qotes with the dict key: `{ 'form': form }`